# Install GitLab on Debian server subdomain of subdomain? (Apache)

Tags: git, apache, debian, subdomain, gitlab

Is it possible to install GitLab on a subdomain of a subdomain? That is, I am trying to install it in a server of a university so it is a subdomain: `ing.universidad.edu.co`. The question is if I can specify GitLab to be accessed through `gitlab.ing.universidad.edu.co` .. will I have to touch the DNS?

Answer (score 0):

In order for the name `gitlab.ing.universidad.edu.co` to be usable by other systems on your network, you will have to make sure it exists in DNS and points to the address of your server.

Once that is done, installing GitLab into a name-based virtual host is a completely normal way to install GitLab.